# ValueError: [] is not in list

Tags: python-3.x

I have some problems with my code.

> This is my code

```
class LocalSessionStorage(Borg):
SessionList = List[Session]
__sessions: SessionList = []

def add_session(self, session: Session):
    self.__sessions.append(session)

def get_session_list(self):
    return self.__sessions

def get_session_by_connection(self, ws_connection: WSConnectionType):
    return [i for i in self.__sessions if i.connection.ws_connection == ws_connection]

def delete_session(self, session: Session):
    index = self.__sessions.index(session)
    self.__sessions.pop(index)
```

> This 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1499, in _stack_context_handle_exception

    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))

  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 315, in wrapped

    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 440, in on_connection_close

    self.on_close()

  File "/opt/rm-interface-platform-transmitter-server/controller/api/v1/ws/handlers/connector.py", line 65, in on_close

    LOCAL_SESSION_STORAGE.delete_session(session)

  File "/opt/rm-interface-platform-transmitter-server/controller/helpers/ws/router/connection_storage.py", line 58, in delete_session

    index = self.__sessions.index(session)

ValueError: [] is not in list
```

I know, that problem is in this method:

```
def delete_session(self, session: Session):
    index = self.__sessions.index(session)
    self.__sessions.pop(index)
```

But i don't understand, how can i resolve it. I hope some one can help me with it.

Comment: Fix indentation in code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, lets go through the code and improve the quality.

1. I would always go for `property` over getters and setters.

**Example:**

```
@property
def sessions(self):
    return self.__sessions
```

**Usage:**

```
YourClass().sessions
```

2. The error that you're getting is actually telling you that `[]` is not in the list, how are you calling these functions? and what's the purpose of the parent class. - From seeing the minimal amount of data in the question; I'd say you're passing invalid data to the functions.